# IndicatorView is only showing one indicator circle, after upgrading to Xcode 12 (Visual Studio Mac - Xamarin)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have a carouselview, for showing pictures.
And an Indicatorview, attached to it.
The IndicatorView is only showing one indicator circle, besides more itens should be shown.
If I set a background color, I can see that the parent view is occupying the correct space.
When I slide between pictures, I can see a small animation, but still only one circle at a time.

I've upgraded Xcode to version 12, and my Visual Studio for Mac is with the latest stable version.
The only change I've made, was downloading xamarin.ios-14.0.0.0.pkg, because, without it, it wouldn't start the app on the phone.
My iPhone is with the final iOS 14.

On the App Store, my App wasn't updated.
So, on my phone, with iOS 14, the indicator view works fine.
The problem only happens on the new debugged version.

```js
<Grid
    BackgroundColor="Black">

    <CarouselView
        x:Name="carousel"
        IndicatorView="indicatorView">

        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        LoadingPlaceholder="loading.gif"
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        BackgroundColor="Black"
                        Source="{Binding Url}">
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

    </CarouselView>

    <IndicatorView
        x:Name="indicatorView"
        VerticalOptions="End"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        IndicatorsShape="Circle"
        IndicatorSize="8"
        IndicatorColor="White"
        Margin="0,0,0,15"
        SelectedIndicatorColor="LightGray" />

</Grid>
```

=== Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.7.7 (build 10)
Installation UUID: aa1a670b-2ee7-474a-b67d-f22b879e6add
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

```
Package version: 612000093
```

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
Mono 6.12.0.93 (2020-02/620cf538206) (64-bit)
Package version: 612000093

=== Roslyn (Language Service) ===

3.7.0-6.20427.1+18ede13943b0bfae1b44ef078b2f3923159bcd32

=== NuGet ===

Version: 5.7.0.6702

=== .NET Core SDK ===

SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/Sdks
SDK Versions:
3.1.402
3.1.401
3.1.302
3.1.301
3.1.300
3.1.200
3.1.102
3.1.101
3.1.100
3.0.101
3.0.100
3.0.100-rc1-014190
3.0.100-preview9-014004
3.0.100-preview8-013656
2.1.701
2.1.505
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== .NET Core Runtime ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
3.1.8
3.1.7
3.1.6
3.1.5
3.1.4
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.1.0
3.0.1
3.0.0
3.0.0-rc1-19456-20
3.0.0-preview9-19423-09
2.1.22
2.1.21
2.1.20
2.1.19
2.1.18
2.1.17
2.1.16
2.1.15
2.1.14
2.1.13
2.1.12
2.1.9

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.12.26
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 12.0 (17219)
Build 12A7209

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 6.20.2.2 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 817b6f72a
Branch: d16-7
Build date: 2020-07-18 18:44:59-0400

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 14.0.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 7ec3751a1
Branch: xcode12
Build date: 2020-09-16 11:33:15-0400

=== Xamarin Designer ===

Version: 16.7.0.495
Hash: 03d50a221
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7-vsmac
Build date: 2020-08-28 13:12:52 UTC

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 11.0.2.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-7/025fde9
Android SDK: /Users/rafaelrasche/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
Supported Android versions:
7.0 (API level 24)
8.0 (API level 26)
8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.4
SDK Build Tools Version: 28.0.3

Build Information:
Mono: 83105ba
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-7@1f3388a
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/proguard6.2.2@ebe9000
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.32.1@1a3276b
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-7@017078f

=== Microsoft OpenJDK for Mobile ===

Java SDK: /Users/rafaelrasche/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android SDK Manager ===

Version: 16.7.0.13
Hash: 8380518
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7~2
Build date: 2020-08-19 22:18:28 UTC

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 16.7.0.24
Hash: bb090a3
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-7
Build date: 2020-08-19 22:18:52 UTC

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 807070010
Git revision: e58142243407a357198d18ee1a37b1e67a702eff
Build date: 2020-09-10 11:48:02-04
Build branch: release-8.7
Xamarin extensions: e58142243407a357198d18ee1a37b1e67a702eff

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.15.6
Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0
Thu Jun 18 20:49:00 PDT 2020
root:xnu-6153.141.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IndicatorView is inside a grid, and HorizontalOptions="Center".
I've just found out that that's the actual problem.

If you change it to HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand", all circles are back.

When you keep this setting as "Center", depending of the number of itens, it could show 1/3 of the circles. I couldn't find the exact formula.

But everything is ok now.

Comment: There was a change on how the circles are shown. Before, all circles were draw. Now, there is max number, and when the count is greater than this limit, the circles also have its own carousel.

Comment: This, saved my day

Comment: IndicatorView's bullets are visible on Android, but on iOS I had to set HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" to get them appear. Seems like a bug. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: Works like a charm. Xamarin 5.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

> The IndicatorView is only showing one indicator circle, besides more itens should be shown.

From shaed code, I can not seeing where set the `x:Name="indicatorView"` for `CarouselView`.

You can modify code as follows:

```
<CarouselView IndicatorView="indicatorView"> // set indicatorView for CarouselView 
  <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      ...
    </DataTemplate>
  </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>

<IndicatorView
  x:Name="indicatorView"
  IsVisible="{Binding CarouselVisible}"
  VerticalOptions="End"
  IndicatorsShape="Circle"
  IndicatorSize="8"
  IndicatorColor="#666666"
  Margin="0,0,0,7"
  SelectedIndicatorColor="#cccccc"
  HorizontalOptions="Center"
/>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for anwsering, but my code sample was incomplete. I've edited with the complete code. One thing that I noticed, is that it shows something like one third of the circles.Example: if the carousel has 9 itens, it show 3 circles, and as I'm sliding, these 3 are animated, but they never increase, to show the user the real count.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRasche Could you share a sample project link here? That will be better to check where problem is.

Comment: Thanks @junior-jiang-msft. Part of the code was missing. I've updated, and I was able to find a simple fix.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRasche Glad you have found the solution! Remember to mark your solution when you have time later.